# How to verify check box is checked or not for iOS app using xamarin ui test

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.uitest

Using xamarin ui test For Android app 
"app.Query(c=>c.Id("chkbox").Invoke("isChecked").Value()).First()". Assuming "chkbox" is the id for the checkbox. Is working fine

But for iOS app how to verify check box is checked or not? or Native method of iOS to check box is checked or not?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can try `app.Tap();`

Answer (score 1):

I belive that you want to check the [isOn](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiswitch/1623690-ison) property of [UISwitch](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiswitch), so something like below should work:

```
app.Query(c=>c.Id("chkbox").Invoke("isOn").Value()).First()
```

Answer (score 0):

This actually works, returning 1 or more AppResults if successful:

To check if set:

```
app.Query(c => c.Switch("chkBox").Property("isOn",true))
```

To check if NOT set:

```
app.Query(c => c.Switch("chkBox").Property("isOn",false))
```

You could use the query part in a WaitForElement if you wanted the test to fail at this point:

```
app.WaitForElement(c => c.Switch("chkBox").Property("isOn", true), "chkBox is unchecked!");
```